# Problema al utilizar Stage en libgdx-Scene2D

Tags: android, libgdx

El problema consiste en que *no puedo ubicar mis objetos sobre la pantalla mas allá de la mitad*. Cuando los voy subiendo llega a un limite y empiezan a superponerse hasta quedar totalmente oculto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi se ve como se come parte de la botonera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi se ve mas claro.

**Acá esta el código.**

```
package ar.com.tedesafio.game.screen;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;

public abstract class AbstractScreen extends Stage implements Screen {

protected final static float WIDTH = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth();
protected final static float HEIGHT = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight();

protected Skin skinGeneral;
private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;

protected AbstractScreen(){
    super( new StretchViewport(HEIGHT, WIDTH, new OrthographicCamera()));
    skinGeneral = new Skin();
    textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("skin/metal-ui.atlas"));
    skinGeneral.addRegions(textureAtlas);
    skinGeneral.load(Gdx.files.internal("skin/metal-ui.json"));
    setDebugAll(true);

}
public abstract void buildStage();

@Override
public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    super.act(delta);
    super.draw();
}
@Override
public void show(){
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    getViewport().update(height, width);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    skinGeneral.dispose();
    textureAtlas.dispose();
}
}
```

**Las pantallas extienden de esta y a todas les pasa lo mismo.**

```
package ar.com.tedesafio.game.minigames.game001;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;

import ar.com.tedesafio.game.logic.Rectangle;
import ar.com.tedesafio.game.screen.AbstractScreen;

public class Game001 extends AbstractScreen {
@Override
public void buildStage() {
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0,0,5000,5000, Color.WHITE);
    addActor(r);
}
}
```

**Básicamente todas las pantallas se manejan así.**

Agrego el codigo del la clase Rectangle

```
public class Rectangle extends Actor {

private Texture texture;

public Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height, Color color) {
    createTexture((int)width, (int)height, color);

    setX(x);
    setY(y);
    setWidth(width);
    setHeight(height);
}

private void createTexture(int width, int height, Color color) {
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(color);
    pixmap.fillRectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    texture = new Texture(pixmap);
    pixmap.dispose();
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    Color color = getColor();
    batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
    batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
}
}
```

Ademas agrego el codigo de la pantalla con botones de la captura

```
public class SelectMenu extends AbstractScreen {

private Table table;
private TextButton [] txtBtnGames;
private TextButton volverBtn;
private final static int CANTIDADGAMES = 5;

public SelectMenu() {
    table = new Table();
    volverBtn = new TextButton("Volver", skinGeneral);
    txtBtnGames = new TextButton[CANTIDADGAMES];
    for(int i=0; i<CANTIDADGAMES; i++) {
        txtBtnGames[i] = new TextButton(""+(i + 1), skinGeneral);
        txtBtnGames[i].getLabel().setFontScale(2);
        switch (i){
            case 0: txtBtnGames[0].addListener(UIfactory.createListener(ScreenEnum.GAME001_MENU));
                break;
            case 1: txtBtnGames[1].addListener(UIfactory.createListener(ScreenEnum.GAME002_MENU));
                break;
            case 2: txtBtnGames[2].addListener(UIfactory.createListener(ScreenEnum.GAME003_MENU));
                break;
            case 3: txtBtnGames[3].addListener(UIfactory.createListener(ScreenEnum.GAME004_MENU));
                break;
            case 4: txtBtnGames[4].addListener(UIfactory.createListener(ScreenEnum.GAME005_MENU));
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void buildStage() {
    volverBtn.getLabel().setFontScale(2);
    volverBtn.addListener(UIfactory.createListener(ScreenEnum.MAIN_MENU));

    table.setTransform(true);
    table.setPosition(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
    table.setOrigin(0, 0);
    table.setScale(4);
    table.setDebug(true);
    for(int i=0; i<CANTIDADGAMES; i++) {
        table.add(txtBtnGames[i]);
        if( i % 2 != 0)
            table.row();
    }
    //table.row();
    table.add(volverBtn);
    addActor(table);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: Puedes poner la clase `Rectangle`

Comment: Yo copie tus clases `Game001` ,`AbstractScreen`, `Rectangle`  y lo ejecute con el proyecto de desktop y el rectangulo se dibuja completo, el problema es en android solamente? ahora mismo no tengo uno para probar

Comment: Perdon por la demora, el problema al parecer era de cache del parametro android:screenOrientation="portrait" dentro del AndroidManifest.xml. Por mas viewport que utilizara la parte negra seguia. Muchas gracias por las respuestas.